# Fixed-Position Div Not Animating With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, css-position

I am trying to get the div with `id="markdown-editor"` to slide over when a button is clicked using JQuery's `Animate` function. `markdown-editor` contains two divs that have `position: fixed`. The div with `id=header` doesn't have any other positioning css (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, etc.), but the other div, where `id=footer`, has `bottom: 0px`. When I animate the `#markdown-editor` div, **everything inside `#markdown-editor` animates correctly except `#footer`**. I know it has something to do with using positioning css, but I'm not sure what to do about it. Below is the pertinent code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="markdown-editor" class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="header" class="row">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 15px;
    z-index: 9001;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 9001;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#menu-button").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#markdown-editor").animate({left: "20%"}, 500, "swing");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes around #menu-button

```
$("#menu-button").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#markdown-editor").animate({left: "20%"}, 500, "swing");
});
```

EDIT

Make sure you're linking to the jQuery library in your head.

Also, try giving #markdown-editor a left value in your css. Also, you need to give it a position. It doesn't matter if the elements inside it have position, the actual element needs a position in order to animate. Has to be fixed, relative, or absolute.

```
#markdown-editor { 
    position: relative; // or fixed or absolute
    left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, that was a typo on my part as I was copying the code in. The problem still stands. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: @BradRoss Also make sure you are linking to the jQuery library in your head.

Comment: Didn't include that as it wasn't important to the problem. I assure you it's there--the first two child divs of `#markdown-editor` are animating just fine.

Comment: Giving `#markdown-editor` a position is not needed--`position` always defaults to `relative` if one isn't given. Giving `left` also doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the first #menu-button in the Javascript portion.

Comment: That was a typo as I was copying my code over. Fixed it, but the problem still stands... Sorry!